# cambiar color a boton con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el sig. codigo:
yo realice los estilos del boton en css y con una consulta lleno una datatable pero no eh podido cambiar el color del boton dependiendo del codigo de la datatable

BD5

```
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablas" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10px"></th>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>Bahia</th>
            <th>Etapa</th>
            <th>Tecnico</th>
            <th>Ayudante_1</th>
            <th>Ayudante_2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

          <?php

            $item = null;
            $valor = null;
            $kandon = ControladorKandon::ctrMostrarKandon($item, $valor);

            foreach ($kandon as $key => $value){


      echo '  <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>'.$value["Codigo"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Time"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["OS"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Bahia"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Etapa"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Tecnico"].'</td>    
              <td>'.$value["Ayudante_1"].'</td> 
              <td>'.$value["Ayudante_2"].'</td>        
            </tr>';
    }
          ?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

y lo que busco es que el boton del background de mi boton cambie a azul dependiendo del color de mi $value[Codigo] pero no eh podido hacerlo

Comment: así creo el boton
 <button class="btn btn-bd5"><p>BD5</p><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>

Comment: Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/316095/edit) tu respuesta en vez de poner un comentario. Que muestra el value["Codigo"]? Donde está situado ese botón dentro del código?

Comment: No necesariamente necesitas PHP para cambiar el color y la apariencia de un botón. Sólo con CSS se puede

Answer (score 0):

### Editado

Para logra lo que quieres basta con usar el atributo `style`, de este modo:

```php
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablas" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10px"></th>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>Bahia</th>
            <th>Etapa</th>
            <th>Tecnico</th>
            <th>Ayudante_1</th>
            <th>Ayudante_2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

          <?php

            $item = null;
            $valor = null;
            $kandon = ControladorKandon::ctrMostrarKandon($item, $valor);

            foreach ($kandon as $key => $value){


      echo '  <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>'.$value["Codigo"].' <button class="btn btn-bd5" style="background-color: '.$value["Color"].';"><p>BD5</p><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button></td>
              <td>'.$value["Time"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["OS"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Bahia"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Etapa"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["Tecnico"].'</td>    
              <td>'.$value["Ayudante_1"].'</td> 
              <td>'.$value["Ayudante_2"].'</td>        
            </tr>';
    }
          ?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Una explicación de lo que hiciste ayudaría mucho a comprender como corregiste el problema del OP

Comment: @Aprendiz me disculpó por la falta de explicación, soy muy malo en eso